# Xamarin iOS: Google Maps SDK - Search Bar

Tags: c#, ios, google-maps, xamarin, uisearchbar

I am developing and iPhone app that can open Google Maps (without leaving the app) and do certain things such as adding marker, etc.

What I would like to do is to add a search bar so that user can search places in the app. I could not find any example like this. Do you think should I implement the search functionality myself or are there any built-in search bar component?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an open source component for Xamarin iOS
https://github.com/ajsmithsw/Xamarin.iOS.GooglePlacesAutocomplete

But if you want, you can make it yourself, it's not so hard. Basically, you need a text field that can take an input, and then construct and call URL with that input. In return, you will receive all matched places.

For example :

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/xml?input=Amoeba&types=establishment&location=37.76999,-122.44696&radius=500&key=YOUR_API_KEY

It will return XML with autocompleted places for name "Amoeba", in 500-meter radius from coordinates 37.76999,-122.4469.

You can find more information in official documentation: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete